# Docusaurus sidebar isn't rendering my front matter

Tags: docusaurus

Basically, a single file out of all them in my project is not working w/ its front matter, and the sidebar and title are showing the file id (just its dir) instead of the `title` I set it

I've copied pasted exact front matter from other files in which it works, and it just doesn't work

My front matter is this:

```
---
title: Mining Pools
---
```

and it renders:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojLa8.png

I expected it to render the title properly, instead of making the id the title and all-around breaking

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the file,`yarn start`-ing, then re-adding the file fixed it